# Add an image to MKMapView (SWIFT)

Tags: image, swift, mkmapview

I'm trying to add an image to MKMapView using SWIFT and I have ZERO coding experience.  Could someone provide me with ALL the sample code necessary to do this?  If there are any placeholder words (like overlay.yourimage.mapView) could you put the place where I need to add my information IN CAPS?  I can't even tell the parts where I'm supposed to add my own information.

I appreciate any responses, I'm a first time poster.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The short answer is no.

This is not a site where people write your code for you. It's a site where you come when you have specific problems with code you've written and need help.

Be warned that MKMapView is a pretty complex framework. If you have zero programming experience it is way, way, WAAAAAAY over your head. You need to start with "Hello World" type stuff and work your way up.

Starting your programming career with trying to customize a map view is like going down a black diamond ski trail the first time you put skis on. You will fail dramatically, and won't be ready for black diamond trails (advanced APIs like map kit) until you do a lot of groundwork.

You can probably find sample code online that deals with adding an image to a map view, but it's not going to make much sense to you at this point, just like a ski instructor explaining how to get through a difficult mogul field won't make much sense to a beginning skier.

Comment: Thanks Duncan.  Your advice aligns with all the sample code I have found which has been majorly complex.  I'll keep working on my fundamentals and hopefully come back to provide my own sample code to this question one day.